# Google Admin SDK API : Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Tags: java, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I want to delete user from google Directory API. I received error while deleting

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

However my code works fine while insert user. I have super admin accounts and I'm using same directory instance for inserting and deleting user. It does work when I'm trying to delete the user.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
public class UserDisable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EmployeeAPI.class);

/** Application name. */
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "User Account Creation";

/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"),
        ".credentials/admin-directory_v1-java-quickstart");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory
        .getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

private static final Random randomGenerator = new Random();

static Directory directoryClient = null;

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
        DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER, DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * 
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = UserDisable.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline").build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
            new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    LOGGER.info("Credentials saved to "
            + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Admin SDK Directory client service.
 * 
 * @return an authorized Directory client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Directory getDirectoryService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Directory.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}

public static void demo(){
    try {
        directoryClient = getDirectoryService();
        removeUser(directoryClient, "Anderson.Paul2@abc.com");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 /**
 * removeGroup removes a group from Google.
 * @param directoryClient a Directory (service) object
 * @param userKey an identifier for a user (e-mail address is the most popular)
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void removeUser(Directory directoryClient, String userKey) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("removeUser() - {}"+ userKey);

    try {
        directoryClient.users().delete(userKey).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("An unknown error occurred: " + e);
    }
}
```

}

Here is error that i have received:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{

  "code" : 403,

  "errors" : [ { 

    "domain" : "global",

    "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",

    "reason" : "forbidden"

  } 
],

  "message" : "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"

}
```

Comment: The message means that the user you are authenticating with does not have permissions to delete users.

Comment: @DaImTo : but I'm insert new user via this super admin account.

Comment: Try and reauthenticate your code, your application.  If you added the ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER scope after authenticating and are still using the refresh token from before this would also cause the error.   Your code looks good to me.  I dont have an admin account so cant test it.

Comment: @DaImTo : I did the same. but same error persist.

Comment: try doing a users.list https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list make sure your not spelling the user wrong?

Comment: @DalmTo I have created this fresh account and going to delete the same. i have checked the same. It is correctly retrieving the same account in list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145279/discussion-between-kashvi-garg-and-daimto).